# Side show using CSS only

Tags: css

So I am creating a slide show only using CSS, but running into two main issues and any help would be appreciated!

1. I would like to add text inside the image, like a few words explain what the picture is but I am unsure how to do that despite my attempts
2. For some reason the last slide is getting cut off. Any idea why?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="fling-minislide">
    <img src="20190417_011307.jpg" alt="Slide 10" />
    <img src="20190417_203230.jpg" alt="Slide 9" />
    <img src="20190420_121746.jpg" alt="Slide 8" />
    <img src="20190428_174640.jpg" alt="Slide 7" />
    <img src="20200103_142544.jpg" alt="Slide 6" />
    <img src="20200104_142904.jpg" alt="Slide 5" />
    <img src="20200411_135421.jpg" alt="Slide 4" />
    <img src="20201016_132909.jpg" alt="Slide 3" />
    <img src="20201225_070106.jpg" alt="Slide 2" />
    <img src="20210416_193029.jpg" alt="Slide 1" />
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.fling-minislide {width:350px; height:300px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.fling-minislide img{ position:absolute; animation:fling-minislide 46s infinite; opacity:0; width: 100%; height: auto;}

@keyframes fling-minislide {25%{opacity:1;} 40%{opacity:0;}}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(10){animation-delay:0s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(9){animation-delay:5s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(8){animation-delay:10s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(7){animation-delay:15s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(6){animation-delay:20s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(5){animation-delay:25s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:30s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:35s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:40s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:45s;}
```

Comment: why not wrap the image and text in a div?

Comment: Just to clarify, I would have 10 different div's (20 in total, opening and closing) for each picture?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should include all img tags in div tag like this.

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="20190417_011307.jpg" alt="Animation Picture">
  <div class="text">
                    <h1>some text</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
```

2. As far as the keyframe is concerned, you should set the animation time as 55S. Then it works fine. The reason why i recommend animation time as 55 sec, the durtion time should be longer the delay time. If not animation will not occur correctly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but maybe I am doing it wrong. Please see below on what I tried and let me know if what I am doing is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fling-minislide">
<img src="20210416_193029 .jpg" alt="Slide 10" >
<div class="text">
                  <h1>some text</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
<div class="fling-minislide">
<img src="20210416_193029 .jpg" alt="Slide 10" >
<div class="text">
                  <h1>some text</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: This was just an example on the coding blocks. I did change the slide and the picture

Comment: i think you should apply animation to each div, not img. therefore, you correct the css.